# Query to identify who can make changes to SQL DB objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, privileges

I am looking for a query to run on SQL server to identify who can change DB objects structure (DLL) within a SQL server.  Please help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for efforts.  I found the following site which gives you multiple queries determining effective database engine permissions.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/determining-effective-database-engine-permissions?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can look in the [Default Trace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-trace-enabled-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT  TE.name AS EventName ,
        T.DatabaseName ,
        t.ObjectName,
        t.NTDomainName ,
        t.ApplicationName ,
        t.LoginName ,
        t.StartTime 
FROM sys.traces tr
cross apply sys.fn_trace_gettable(CONVERT(VARCHAR(150), 
    ( SELECT f.[value] FROM sys.fn_trace_getinfo(tr.id) f WHERE f.property = 2 )), DEFAULT) T
JOIN sys.trace_events TE ON T.EventClass = TE.trace_event_id
WHERE   
tr.is_default = 1
and name like 'Object:%'
ORDER BY t.StartTime ;
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I found the following solution above.